# Hash and array interrelation on a value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, hash

I have an array like this,

```
array1 = [{"name"=>"Bob"}, {"age"=>"30"}]
```

Now, I used a condition to find an element from array where age is 30.

```
hash1 = array1.find { |h| h['age'] == "30" }, which gives a hash.   --> {"age"=>30}
```

Now I changed the value from that hash as,

```
 hash1['age'] = 31, so hash1 becomes --> {"age"=>31}
```

My question is when I again print the value in array, surprisingly the value of the age in the array updated to '31' and I just changed it in the hash object, but how the array value changed??

```
array1 --> became [{"name"=>"Bob"}, {"age"=>31}]
```

Is there any reason behind this.Thanks in advance. :-)

Comment: You're referencing the same object (the hash).

Comment: But, I am not changing the value of array directly?

Comment: You're changing a value of a value *in* the array.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's because it is doing a "shallow copy" of the object.A shallow copy means that only the fundamental datatypes actually get copied into new objects, everything else gets copied as a reference to the original object.

Check this [link](http://thingsaaronmade.com/blog/ruby-shallow-copy-surprise.html) out for more details on the issue

Comment: There's no shallow copy here either; it's simply a reference.